# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Double'

Tags: swift, double

I am implementing `AudioVisualizer` and I am trying to calculate time of audio but I am getting below error

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float' and 'Double'

Here is my code:

```
 var lowPassReslts: Double = 0.0
 var lowPassReslts1: Double = 0.0

 let ALPHA: Float = 1.05
    
 let averagePowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 0)))
 lowPassReslts = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassReslts //HERE i am getting error which i mention above
    
 let averagePowerForChannel1 = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 1)))
 lowPassReslts1 = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel1 + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassReslts1 //HERE i am getting error
```

This above code have converted from Objective-C. This code works perfect in Objective-C but it is not working in Swift. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error?

[image: Please See Screen Shot]

Comment: On why it works on ObjC and not Swift: Swift is more verbose and strict on numerical operations, whereas ObjC isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var lowPassReslts: Double = 0.0
    var lowPassReslts1: Double = 0.0

    let ALPHA: Float = 1.05

    let averagePowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 0)))
    lowPassReslts = Double(ALPHA * Float(averagePowerForChannel) + (1.0 - ALPHA) * Float(lowPassReslts))

    let averagePowerForChannel1 = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 1)))
    lowPassReslts1 = Double(ALPHA * Float(averagePowerForChannel1) + (1.0 - ALPHA) * Float(lowPassReslts1))
```

Comment: Swift prefer Double over Float, so It's better to have the ALPHA as double instead of doing a couple of conversion from double to float to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in objective C, you can not do operation on 2-different type of variables (as **Swift Language is Type-Safe**).

To do any arithmetic calculation the type of both operand must be same.

> If you do not specify the type of the variable then swift inferences the type from its value.

For eg.

```
let a = 10    //Swift consider it -> Int type 
let b = 20.0  //Swift consider it -> Double type 

let result = a * b  //Gives compile time error for the operand type 

let result = Double(a) * b  //No error, as Int is converted to Double
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make same data type for both like both are double or both are float.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parameter type of ALPHA as `Double` or change your lowPassReslts as `Float`.

Try the following code:

```
var lowPassReslts: Double = 0.0
var lowPassReslts1: Double = 0.0

let ALPHA: Double = 1.05

let averagePowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 0)))
lowPassReslts = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassReslts 

let averagePowerForChannel1 = pow(10, (0.05 * audioPlayer.averagePower(forChannel: 1)))
lowPassReslts1 = ALPHA * averagePowerForChannel1 + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassReslts1
```

In swift there is no need to declare the variable type. You can directly declare the variable as,

```
  var lowPassReslts = 0.0
  var lowPassReslts1 = 0.0
  let ALPHA = 1.05
```

Try any of the above method. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pow(Double, Double) it accepts the double and returns the double.

let ALPHA: Float = 1.05, you explicitly declared the Float(change the naming convention, should not be all caps).

in swift, you cannot do any binary operation with two different types.

Solution: change the alpha type to double or don't declare the data type else convert it to double during operation.